# `lein deploy clojars` gives Connection reset by peer: socket write error

Tags: clojure, leiningen, clojars

I get the error `I/O exception (java.net.SocketException)
caught when processing request: Connection reset by peer:
socket write error` when I try to deploy a lib to clojars. I
tried it several times, in a span of 20 days.

```
C:\Users\oskarkv\Desktop\jmonkeyengine-read-only\engine>lein deploy clojars
No credentials found for clojars
See `lein help deploy` for how to configure credentials.
Username: oskarkv
Password:
Wrote C:\Users\oskarkv\Desktop\jmonkeyengine-read-only\engine\pom.xml
Created C:\Users\oskarkv\Desktop\jmonkeyengine-read-only\engine\target\jmonkeyengine-3.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
Could not find metadata org.clojars.oskarkv:jmonkeyengine:3.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml in clojars (https://clojars.org/repo/)
Sending org/clojars/oskarkv/jmonkeyengine/3.0.1-SNAPSHOT/jmonkeyengine-3.0.1-20130817.134749-1.pom (2k)
    to https://clojars.org/repo/
Sending org/clojars/oskarkv/jmonkeyengine/3.0.1-SNAPSHOT/jmonkeyengine-3.0.1-20130817.134749-1.jar (79156k)
    to https://clojars.org/repo/
aug 17, 2013 3:48:24 EM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryExecute
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
aug 17, 2013 3:48:24 EM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryExecute
INFO: Retrying request
aug 17, 2013 3:48:54 EM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryExecute
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
aug 17, 2013 3:48:54 EM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryExecute
INFO: Retrying request
aug 17, 2013 3:49:24 EM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryExecute
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
aug 17, 2013 3:49:24 EM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryExecute
INFO: Retrying request
Could not transfer artifact org.clojars.oskarkv:jmonkeyengine:jar:3.0.1-20130817.134749-1 from/to clojars (https://clojars.org/repo/): Connection rese
t by peer: socket write error
Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact org.clojars.oskarkv:jmonkeyengine:jar:3.0.1-20130817.134749-1 from/to clojars (https://clojars
.org/repo/): Connection reset by peer: socket write error
```

Maybe size matters, because I tried to deploy a project I
just created by doing `lein new testclojars`, and that seemed
to work.

```
C:\Users\oskarkv\Desktop\jmonkeyengine-read-only\test\testclojars>lein deploy clojars
WARNING: please set :description in project.clj.
WARNING: please set :url in project.clj.
No credentials found for clojars
See `lein help deploy` for how to configure credentials.
Username: oskarkv
Password:
Wrote C:\Users\oskarkv\Desktop\jmonkeyengine-read-only\test\testclojars\pom.xml
Created C:\Users\oskarkv\Desktop\jmonkeyengine-read-only\test\testclojars\target\testclojars-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
Could not find metadata org.clojars.oskarkv:testclojars:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml in clojars (https://clojars.org/repo/)
Sending org/clojars/oskarkv/testclojars/0.1.0-SNAPSHOT/testclojars-0.1.0-20130817.133946-1.pom (2k)
    to https://clojars.org/repo/
Sending org/clojars/oskarkv/testclojars/0.1.0-SNAPSHOT/testclojars-0.1.0-20130817.133946-1.jar (2k)
    to https://clojars.org/repo/
Could not find metadata org.clojars.oskarkv:testclojars/maven-metadata.xml in clojars (https://clojars.org/repo/)
Sending org/clojars/oskarkv/testclojars/0.1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml (1k)
    to https://clojars.org/repo/
Sending org/clojars/oskarkv/testclojars/maven-metadata.xml (1k)
    to https://clojars.org/repo/
C:\Users\oskarkv\Desktop\jmonkeyengine-read-only\test\testclojars>
```

Any ideas of what could be wrong?

Comment: What is the version of your JDK?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is a 20 MB limit on files that one sends to clojars.